# Get model data from monogo database basing on custom ID name in featherJs api

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, feathersjs

I would like to get user data based on id attribute mentioned in URL : (`/user/488/all`) using FratherJS framework

```
   var mongooseService = require('feathers-mongoose');
    ...
    app.use('user/:id/all', mongooseService({
                name: 'agency',
                Model: require('models/user') //user.id is the ID of user model 
            }));
    ...
```

i don't want to use this url : `/user/488`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feathers standard URLs are intentionally built around [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) URL best practises so, although not impossible, I would only break with it if there is a very good reason. To be compatible with existing clients you can create aliases using a [custom service](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/services.html):

```
const mongooseService = require('feathers-mongoose');

app.use('/users', mongooseService({
    name: 'agency',
    Model: require('models/user') //user.id is the ID of user model 
}));

class UserAliases {
  async find(params) {
    const { id } = params.route;

    return this.app.service('users').get(id, params);
  }

  setup(app) {
    this.app = app;
  }
}
app.use('/user/:id/all', new UserAliases());
```

Comment: thank's, just a little bit modification : replace const { id } = params.route; by const { id } = params;